# SQL table rows to Column

Tags: sql, sql-server

Please check my doubt before you say duplicated question, As I have some tables and I trying to get report from that. I am posting my select statement below,

```
SELECT JobDetails.JobCode,JobDetails.ReceiptDate,JobDetails.DeliveryDate,JobDetails.CompletionDate,JobDetails.BranchName,RepairDetails.Repair_Remarks,JobDetails.FinalRemarks,
       JobDetails.JobCommentCSR,JobDetails.BrandName, JobDetails.ModelName,JobDetails.IMEICode,JobDetails.SerialNo,CustomerDTL.CustomerName,CustomerDTL.MobileNumber,JobDetails.WarrantyType,
       RepairDetails.Tech_Name,RepairDetails.Device_Condition,RepairDetails.Levels,

       ItemMaster.ItemName,ItemMaster.ItemCode,PartsIssueDetails.SparePrice
From JobDetails
Right Join CustomerDTL On
     JobDetails.JobCode=CustomerDTL.JobCode
Right Join RepairDetails On
     JobDetails.JobCode=RepairDetails.JobCode
Right Join PartsIssueDetails On
     JobDetails.JobCode=PartsIssueDetails.JobCode
Right Join ItemMaster On
     PartsIssueDetails.ItemName=ItemMaster.ItemCode
Where 
(JobDetails.CompletionDate Between @Date1 and @Date2) AND JobDetails.BrandName=@Brand
)
```

I am getting the result as

```
╔═══════════╦═════════════╦══════════════╦════════════════╦════════════╦════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╦═══════════════════════════════╦═══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╦═══════════╦══════════════╦══════════╦══════════╦══════════════╦══════════════╦══════════════╦═════════════════════╦═════════════════════╦═════════════════════════════════════════════════════╦════════════════════════════════════╦══════════════════╦════════════╗
║ JobCode   ║ ReceiptDate ║ DeliveryDate ║ CompletionDate ║ BranchName ║ Repair_Remarks                                         ║ FinalRemarks                  ║ JobCommentCSR                                             ║ BrandName ║ ModelName    ║ IMEICode ║ SerialNo ║ CustomerName ║ MobileNumber ║ WarrantyType ║ Tech_Name           ║ Device_Condition    ║ Levels                                              ║ ItemName                           ║ ItemCode         ║ SparePrice ║ 
╠═══════════╬═════════════╬══════════════╬════════════════╬════════════╬════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╬═══════════════════════════════╬═══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╬═══════════╬══════════════╬══════════╬══════════╬══════════════╬══════════════╬══════════════╬═════════════════════╬═════════════════════╬═════════════════════════════════════════════════════╬════════════════════════════════════╬══════════════════╬════════════╣
║ 201507501 ║ 15-Jul-15   ║ 30-Aug-15    ║ 23-Aug-15      ║ xxx        ║ need replace lcd approved 75                           ║ replace lcd approved 75       ║ Screen broken need full check up                          ║ xx        ║ ST3-GO-77    ║ aaaa     ║ aaa      ║ 1111         ║ N            ║ zzz          ║ HW Part Discoloured ║ Level 2             ║ LCD ST3-GO-77 (Tab3-GO)                             ║ 26-05012-0003201                   ║ 75               ║            ║
║ 201507501 ║ 15-Jul-15   ║ 30-Aug-15    ║ 23-Aug-15      ║ xxx        ║ need replace lcd approved 75                           ║ replace lcd approved 75       ║ Screen broken need full check up                          ║ xx        ║ ST3-GO-77    ║ aaaa     ║ aaa      ║ 111          ║ N            ║ zzz          ║ HW Part Discoloured ║ Level 2             ║ Touch ST3-GO-77 (Tab3-GO)                           ║ 26-05012-0003201                   ║ 0                ║            ║
║ 201508667 ║ 5-Aug-15    ║ 17-Aug-15    ║ 16-Aug-15      ║ xxx        ║ NEED RE-ASSEMBLE AND SOFTWARE                          ║ RE-ASSEMBLE AND SOFTWARE      ║ Unit not charging                                         ║ xx        ║ SSR2-1-50-5M ║ xxxxxxx  ║ aaaa     ║ bbb          ║ 11111        ║ Y            ║ aaa                 ║ HW Part Discoloured ║ Level 2                                             ║ Service Level 2                    ║ Level L2         ║ 73.5       ║
║ 201508668 ║ 5-Aug-15    ║ 8-Aug-15     ║ 5-Aug-15       ║ xxx        ║ NEED REPLACE RECIEVER AND SOFTWARE                     ║ REPLACE RECEIVER AND SOFTWARE ║ Calling problem,Sound Speaker not good need full check up ║ xxx       ║ SSR1-5-8M    ║ xxxxxxx  ║ aaaa     ║ ccc          ║ 111          ║ Y            ║ zzz                 ║ HW Part Dirty       ║ Level 2                                             ║ RECEIVER 0.01W KINGSTATE SSR1-5-8M ║ 29S02-106B0-SH0S ║ 2.78       ║ 
║ 201508668 ║ 5-Aug-15    ║ 8-Aug-15     ║ 5-Aug-15       ║ xxx        ║ NEED REPLACE RECIEVER AND SOFTWARE                     ║ REPLACE RECEIVER AND SOFTWARE ║ Calling problem,Sound Speaker not good need full check up ║ xx        ║ SSR1-5-8M    ║ xxxxxxx  ║ aaaa     ║ ccc          ║ 111          ║ Y            ║ zzz                 ║ HW Part Dirty       ║ Level 2                                             ║ Service Level 2                    ║ SICO L2          ║ 73.5       ║
║ 201508671 ║ 5-Aug-15    ║ 23-Aug-15    ║ 9-Aug-15       ║ xxx        ║ NEED REPLACE LCD APPROVED 185 REPLACE LCD Approved 185 ║ Lcd Broken need full check up ║ xx                                                        ║ SSR1-5-8M ║ xxxxxxx      ║ aaaa     ║ Madu     ║ 111          ║ N            ║ zzz          ║ HW Part Discoloured ║ Level 2             ║ 5" TOUCH PANEL AND LCM MODULE (LAMINATED) SSR1-5-8M ║ 29C10-052A0-L00R                   ║ 185              ║            ║
╚═══════════╩═════════════╩══════════════╩════════════════╩════════════╩════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╩═══════════════════════════════╩═══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╩═══════════╩══════════════╩══════════╩══════════╩══════════════╩══════════════╩══════════════╩═════════════════════╩═════════════════════╩═════════════════════════════════════════════════════╩════════════════════════════════════╩══════════════════╩════════════╝
```

You can see here multiple times coming the jobcode, because of the parts. How I can get the result like below.

```
╔═══════════╦═════════════╦══════════════╦════════════════╦════════════╦════════════════════════════════════╦═══════════════════════════════╦═══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╦═══════════╦══════════════╦══════════╦══════════╦══════════════╦══════════════╦══════════════╦═════════════════════╦═════════════════════╦═════════════════════════╦═════════════════════════════════════════════════════╦══════════════════╦═══════════════════════════╦═════════════════════════════════════════════════════╦══════════════════╦════════════╗
║ JobCode   ║ ReceiptDate ║ DeliveryDate ║ CompletionDate ║ BranchName ║ Repair_Remarks                     ║ FinalRemarks                  ║ JobCommentCSR                                             ║ BrandName ║ ModelName    ║ IMEICode ║ SerialNo ║ CustomerName ║ MobileNumber ║ WarrantyType ║ Tech_Name           ║ Device_Condition    ║ Levels                  ║ ItemName                                            ║ ItemCode         ║ SparePrice                ║ ItemName                                            ║ ItemCode         ║ SparePrice ║
╠═══════════╬═════════════╬══════════════╬════════════════╬════════════╬════════════════════════════════════╬═══════════════════════════════╬═══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╬═══════════╬══════════════╬══════════╬══════════╬══════════════╬══════════════╬══════════════╬═════════════════════╬═════════════════════╬═════════════════════════╬═════════════════════════════════════════════════════╬══════════════════╬═══════════════════════════╬═════════════════════════════════════════════════════╬══════════════════╬════════════╣
║ 201507501 ║ 15-Jul-15   ║ 30-Aug-15    ║ 23-Aug-15      ║ xxx        ║ need replace lcd approved 75       ║ replace lcd approved 75       ║ Screen broken need full check up                          ║ xx        ║ ST3-GO-77    ║ aaaa     ║ aaa      ║ 1111         ║ N            ║ zzz          ║ HW Part Discoloured ║ Level 2             ║ LCD ST3-GO-77 (Tab3-GO) ║ 26-05012-0003201                                    ║ 75               ║ Touch ST3-GO-77 (Tab3-GO) ║ 26-05012-0003201                                    ║ 0                ║            ║
║ 201508667 ║ 5-Aug-15    ║ 17-Aug-15    ║ 16-Aug-15      ║ xxx        ║ NEED RE-ASSEMBLE AND SOFTWARE      ║ RE-ASSEMBLE AND SOFTWARE      ║ Unit not charging                                         ║ xx        ║ SSR2-1-50-5M ║ xxxxxxx  ║ aaaa     ║ bbb          ║ 11111        ║ Y            ║ aaa                 ║ HW Part Discoloured ║ Level 2                 ║ Service Level 2                                     ║ Level L2         ║ 73.5                      ║                                                     ║                  ║            ║
║ 201508668 ║ 5-Aug-15    ║ 8-Aug-15     ║ 5-Aug-15       ║ xxx        ║ NEED REPLACE RECIEVER AND SOFTWARE ║ REPLACE RECEIVER AND SOFTWARE ║ Calling problem,Sound Speaker not good need full check up ║ xxx       ║ SSR1-5-8M    ║ xxxxxxx  ║ aaaa     ║ ccc          ║ 111          ║ Y            ║ zzz                 ║ HW Part Dirty       ║ Level 2                 ║ RECEIVER 0.01W KINGSTATE SSR1-5-8M                  ║ 29S02-106B0-SH0S ║ 2.78                      ║ Service Level 2                                     ║ Level L2         ║ 73.5       ║
║ 201508671 ║ 5-Aug-15    ║ 23-Aug-15    ║ 9-Aug-15       ║ xxx        ║ NEED REPLACE LCD APPROVED 185 AED  ║ REPLACE LCD Approved 185      ║ Lcd Broken need full check up                             ║ xx        ║ SSR1-5-8M    ║ xxxxxxx  ║ aaaa     ║ Madu         ║ 111          ║ N            ║ zzz                 ║ HW Part Discoloured ║ Level 2                 ║ 5" TOUCH PANEL AND LCM MODULE (LAMINATED) SSR1-5-8M ║ 29C10-052A0-L00R ║ 185                       ║ 5" TOUCH PANEL AND LCM MODULE (LAMINATED) SSR1-5-8M ║ 29C10-052A0-L00R ║ 185        ║
╚═══════════╩═════════════╩══════════════╩════════════════╩════════════╩════════════════════════════════════╩═══════════════════════════════╩═══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╩═══════════╩══════════════╩══════════╩══════════╩══════════════╩══════════════╩══════════════╩═════════════════════╩═════════════════════╩═════════════════════════╩═════════════════════════════════════════════════════╩══════════════════╩═══════════════════════════╩═════════════════════════════════════════════════════╩══════════════════╩════════════╝
```

Help me to solve this issue... Maximum parts for the one job is 4.

Comment: Which RDBMS is this for? Please add a tag to specify whether you're using `mysql`, `postgresql`, `sql-server`, `oracle` or `db2` - or something else entirely.

Comment: sql server , sorry for that.

Comment: Try changing `SELECT` to `SELECT DISTINCT`

Comment: please check my result , its like pivot table. not sure how to use in this scenario.

Comment: @NAJEEB: I don't understand from your data which field generate duplication.

Comment: except itemCode,ItemName, and price. please jobcdode:201507501 in my result its coming multiple times,bcoz of the items used(two items used for that job) so i want to show that look like second one.

Comment: It looks like you want to GROUP BY JobCode but then for each row in the group append ItemName, ItemCode & SparePrice as extra columns.  Is that correct?  It seems BrandName and CustomerName differ in your example between grouped rows (possibly typos?) and what would you put for Levels?

Comment: exactly what you said @Quantumplate i want to show it extra column if there is more than one items for the job. Levels always number like 1,2,2.5...my example changed little bit when its updated here and there.

Comment: i want show Customer name and brand and all in that grouped rows too but only one time like jobcode. simply i want to show this multi lines in a single line.

Comment: use left join instead of right join

Comment: Your customer name is different, how you want to choose the customer name to display?

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to create a CTE or derived table from PartsIssueDetails and ItemMaster that returns one row for each JobCode. You can do the pivoting most likely easier with case statement and row_number, with something like this:

```
select
  PID.JobCode,
  max(case when RN = 1 then IM.ItemName end) as ItemName1,
  max(case when RN = 1 then IM.ItemCode end) as ItemCode1,
  max(case when RN = 1 then PID.SparePrice end) as SparePrice1,
  max(case when RN = 2 then IM.ItemName end) as ItemName2,
  max(case when RN = 2 then IM.ItemCode end) as ItemCode2,
  max(case when RN = 2 then PID.SparePrice end) as SparePrice2,
  ...
from (
  select
    PID.JobCode,
    IM.ItemName,
    IM.ItemCode,
    PID.SparePrice,
    row_number() over (partition by PID.JobCode order by IM.ItemName) as RN
  from
    PartsIssueDetails PID
    left outer join ItemMaster IM On PID.ItemName=IM.ItemCode
) X
group by PID.JobCode
```

This is just a guess because you didn't provide any example data or table structure.

I also assumed you need to use left outer join instead of right, that makes more sense to me.

Comment: I posted the result in the question. Four table is there , JobDetails,CustomerDtls,PartsIssuedtl and ItemMaster. Except ItemMaster table identifier is JobCode, ItemMaster and Partsissuedtl are idenitified by itemname(partsissuedtls) and itemcode(itemcode). You answer is more near i guess. now i am getting error: The multi-part identifier could not be bound. with pid.jobcode,im.itemname,im,itemcode,pid.spareprice.

Comment: @NAJEEB If you don't still figure out what to do, create an example in SQL Fiddle.

Answer (score 0):

Add a column rowNumber: ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY JobCode ORDER BY JobCode)

Example:

```
declare @table1 table (jobCode varchar(20), customerName varchar(20))
declare @table2 table (customerName varchar(20), brandName varchar(20))

insert into @table1 values('001', 'Pablo')
insert into @table1 values('002', 'Dima')
insert into @table1 values('003', 'Mike')

insert into @table2 values('Pablo', 'BMW')
insert into @table2 values('Pablo', 'Audi')
insert into @table2 values('Dima', 'Mercedes')
insert into @table2 values('Mike', 'Lada')
insert into @table2 values('Mike', 'Hyundai')

select t1.jobCode, t1.customerName, t2.brandName
from @table1 t1
Right Join @table2 t2 On t1.customerName=t2.customerName
order by t1.jobCode

-- without dublicates
select * from
    (select t1.jobCode, t1.customerName, t2.brandName,
      ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY JobCode ORDER BY JobCode) as rowNumber
    from @table1 t1
    Right Join @table2 t2 On t1.customerName=t2.customerName
    ) as tmpTable
where tmpTable.rowNumber=1
order by jobCode
```